# How to make the client of proxy server keep alive?

Tags: proxy, netty

I want to make the client of proxy server keepAlive. Thus, I don't want the proxy client to make a tcp close handshake everytime.

Please look at [this example in netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java).

Adding the keepAlive option to this example doesn't seem to work properly. Because it makes a client and connect everytime the server get request and close the client when the response is arrived.

Then how can I make my proxy client keepAlive? Is there any reference/example for it?

Comment: The term *use a channel* is quite unclear as it may differ drastically from one case to an other. Would you be more explicit on describing how you are using the `Channel`? It would be helpful to add extra code.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @tmarwen. I edited the question to clarify my problem. Could you take a look again?

Comment: Thanks for adding more context. Still unfortunately unclear on which end you are trying to keep the connection live? As your problem involves a proxy handler, you have two connections involved and the solution will vary depending on which one you are trying to keep alive. Would you please add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using SO_KEEPALIVE socket option doesn't mean that the server (or the other peer in the connection) should ignore an explicit request to close the connection. It helps in cases like

- Idle sessions timing-out/getting killed by the other end due to non-activity
- Idle or long-running requests being disconnected by a firewall in-between after a certain time passes (e.g. 1 hour, for resource clean-up purposes).

If the client's logic is not to re-use the same socket for different requests (i.e. if its application logic uses a new socket for each request), there's nothing you can do about that on your proxy.

The same argument is valid for the "back-end" side of your proxy as well. If the server you're proxying to doesn't allow the socket to be re-used, and explicitly closes a connection after a request is served, that wouldn't work as you wanted either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not closing the connection on your side then the proxy is. Different proxy servers will behave in different ways.

Try sending Connection: Keep-Alive as a header.

If that doesn't work, try also sending Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive as a header.